# Postgres array concatenate each item

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

In Postgres 12 I have a starting `text[]` array: `{test1,test2,test3}`

I want to:

- append `.id` to each item, and
- return the concatenated result as text:

```
test1.id,test2.id.id,test3.id
```

I have tried to concatenate the array, and I just get:
`{test1,test2,test3}` (with curly braces)

(I have not even got to appending `.id` to each)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_agg()
    RETURNS TEXT
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    test_array text[];
BEGIN
    test_array := array_append(test_array, 'test1');
    test_array := array_append(test_array, 'test2');
    test_array := array_append(test_array, 'test3');
    RETURN string_agg(test_array::text, ';');
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

select test_agg();
```

Comment: You want `array_to_string()` not `string_agg()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks! This has got me the second part! Any idea how to append to each item?

Comment: `RETURN array_to_string(test_array, '.id,') || '.id'` seems to work ... The appended `.id` at the end doesn't feel like a nice solution though :(